# Problema al realizar migración de repositorio git

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Anteriormente usaba el repositorio de google, pero después me cambié a github, para realizar el cambio, prácticamente lo que hice fue hacerle un push por cada branch (sin migrar también el historial), seguí trabajando como si nada por un tiempo, pero hoy por primera vez después de la migración hice mi primer merge y me di cuenta de que no se agregaban los cambios previos a la migración, pues los cambios no estaban commiteados, un ejemplo es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto necesito encontrar una forma de que sea posible hacer un merge en el cual compare las diferencias de todo el documento o encontrar una forma de importar el registro de commits de google a github

Comment: La pregunta la encuentro demasiado larga y no encuentro relacion entre el titulo y la descripcion, puedes aclarar un poco cual es el problema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para resolver el problema tuve que revisar el historial de commits de Google e ir realizando cada cambio manualmente.